# Windows 7 does not fire DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2 event?

Tags: winapi, bho, beforenavigate2

I have a BHO that is supposed to intercept the DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2 events when Windows Explorer is browsing the local disks. It works well in XP and Vista, but stopped working in Windows 7 RC.

Turns out, Windows 7 RC stopped sending the DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2 events when the local folders are browsed! It does send other events to my BHO (such as DISPID_DOWNLOADBEGIN, etc.), but I need DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2.

Can anyone confirm this and/or offer a possible workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the Win7 sources, it definitely looks like the DWebBrowserEvents interface isn't called by the shell anymore (which sorta makes sense because IE was fully pulled out of the shell).  Unfortunately, I don't know what the replacement is.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your comment, it's nice to be able to hear from someone who can look into the Win7 sources :-) However, it seems that other events of the DWebBrowserEvents interface do get fired by Win7. I've recompiled the source of the IEHelper sample (found it in MSDN) and it shows other events such as DISPID_DOWNLOADBEGIN, DISPID_PROGRESSCHANGE, etc. All the regular events are present except for DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: OK, Windows 7 RTM finally arrived, the bug is still there: DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2, etc. get logged, but DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2is missing. Microsoft, why are you doing this to me? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's over a year late, but here's a workaround:  Simply set an API hook on `IShellBrowser::BrowseObject` using an API hook library such as [MinHook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/LibMinHook.aspx).  See here for sample code that does this: [API Hook on a COM object function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692836/)

This will route navigations in ALL `IShellBrowser` instances through your detour.  But, `IShellBrowser` extends `IOleWindow`, so you can use `IOleWindow::GetWindow` and `SendMessage` to work with an individual `IShellBrowser` instance whose window you've subclassed.