# Find index of particular function in COM Interface's Vtable

Tags: c++, com, vtable, directdraw

I'm trying to hook the `SetCooperativeLevel` function in the DirectDraw object. My goal is very similar to the one in this question [API Hook on a COM object function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692836/api-hook-on-a-com-object-function) however the only problem is that I don't know the exact offset in `IDirectDraw`'s vtable for `SetCooperativeLevel`. Is there anyway to glean this from perhaps `<ddraw.h>` or programatically?

Here's the interface declaration for `IDirectDraw`, however I'm unsure how this corresponds to the vtable.

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE_( IDirectDraw, IUnknown )
{
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface) (THIS_ REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR * ppvObj) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef) (THIS)  PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release) (THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Compact)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateClipper)(THIS_ DWORD, LPDIRECTDRAWCLIPPER FAR*, IUnknown FAR * ) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreatePalette)(THIS_ DWORD, LPPALETTEENTRY, LPDIRECTDRAWPALETTE FAR*, IUnknown FAR * ) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateSurface)(THIS_  LPDDSURFACEDESC, LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE FAR *, IUnknown FAR *) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DuplicateSurface)( THIS_ LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE, LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE FAR * ) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(EnumDisplayModes)( THIS_ DWORD, LPDDSURFACEDESC, LPVOID, LPDDENUMMODESCALLBACK ) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(EnumSurfaces)(THIS_ DWORD, LPDDSURFACEDESC, LPVOID,LPDDENUMSURFACESCALLBACK ) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(FlipToGDISurface)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetCaps)( THIS_ LPDDCAPS, LPDDCAPS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetDisplayMode)( THIS_ LPDDSURFACEDESC) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetFourCCCodes)(THIS_  LPDWORD, LPDWORD ) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetGDISurface)(THIS_ LPDIRECTDRAWSURFACE FAR *) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetMonitorFrequency)(THIS_ LPDWORD) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetScanLine)(THIS_ LPDWORD) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetVerticalBlankStatus)(THIS_ LPBOOL ) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Initialize)(THIS_ GUID FAR *) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(RestoreDisplayMode)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetCooperativeLevel)(THIS_ HWND, DWORD) PURE;    // I'm trying to hook this
    STDMETHOD(SetDisplayMode)(THIS_ DWORD, DWORD,DWORD) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(WaitForVerticalBlank)(THIS_ DWORD, HANDLE ) PURE;
};
```

Comment: Just count, starting at 0.  So it is 20 * 4 for 32-bit code, 20 * 8 for 64-bit code.  Watch out for inherited interfaces.  This one only inherits IUnknown and already has its 3 methods listed.  Not otherwise typical in IDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: The vtable is laid out in exactly the same order the interface functions are declared.

Comment: Yes basically you need to know two things - the actual order is the order of declaration (including inherited interfaces esp. IUnknown) and that you can build a binary with specific call, set a break point, switch to disassembly and quick-lookup the index checking what compiler generated for specific method.