# How to look up vtable index of a method on the IWinHttpRequest interface?

Tags: dll, vtable

I assume it's in winhttp.dll somewhere, but I can't find any reference to it by dumping the DLL using bindump.  Anyone have any suggestions on how I can find the vtable index of a method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find index of particular function in COM Interface's Vtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958962/find-index-of-particular-function-in-com-interfaces-vtable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is in the IDL file, `httprequest.idl`.

```
interface IWinHttpRequest : IDispatch
{
    [id(DISPID_HTTPREQUEST_SETPROXY), helpstring("Specify proxy configuration")]
    HRESULT SetProxy([in] HTTPREQUEST_PROXY_SETTING ProxySetting,
                     [in, optional] VARIANT ProxyServer,
                     [in, optional] VARIANT BypassList);

    [id(DISPID_HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS), helpstring("Specify authentication credentials")]
    HRESULT SetCredentials([in] BSTR UserName,
                     [in] BSTR Password,
         [in] HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FLAGS Flags);

    ....
```

From this you can read off the method indices. It's a bit tricky because you first have to count the method indices of the base interface `IDispatch`.

```
// IUnknown
0: QueryInterface
1: AddRef
2: Release
// IDispatch
3: GetTypeInfoCount
4: GetTypeInfo
5: GetIDsOfNames
6: Invoke
// IWinHttpRequest
7: SetProxy
8: SetCredentials
... etc. ...
```

You can remove the tedium by [using the`offsetof` macro](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/29/10406191.aspx).