# Access to file list from Explorer Bar

Tags: windows, com, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I have created simple Explorer Bar extension for Windows explorer. How can I get access to the file list in Explorer window from my bar? And how can I change current folder in Explorer window?

Comment: Did you lookup MSDN ? Did you find anything useful ?

Comment: I did but without any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, this is how it works. Your bar object should implement `IObjectWithSite`and receive a site pointer. Query that for `IServiceProvider`, and call `QueryService` requesting `IShellBrowser` interface. That's your portal to everything else of interest. E.g. `IShellBrowser::QueryActiveShellView` to get the currently displayed view; `IShellBrowser::BrowseObject` to navigate to a different folder.

Comment: May be you know how can I hook changing of selected files list?

Comment: You sink `DWebBrowserEvents2` from shell browser, and handle `NavigateComplete2` event. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692836/api-hook-on-a-com-object-function

Comment: This event is fired when user enter new folder. But I need event when user select or deselect files in shell view window. Does (undocumented?) DShellNameSpaceEvents has any relation to the problem?